# Python getstatusoutput replacement not returning full output

Tags: python, pipe, stdout

I came across this great replacment for the `getstatusoutput()` function in Python 2.* which works equally well on Unix and Windows.  However, I think there is something wrong with the way the `output` is constructed.  It only returns the last line of the output, but I can't figure out why.  Any help would be awesome.

```
def getstatusoutput(cmd):
    """Return (status, output) of executing cmd in a shell."""
    """This new implementation should work on all platforms."""
    import subprocess
    pipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
    output = "".join(pipe.stdout.readlines())
    sts = pipe.returncode
    if sts is None: sts = 0
    return sts, output
```

Comment: Why don't you use `subprocess.check_call` inside a try block?  You can get the return code (if it's non-zero) in the `except` part.

Comment: What if I want the output even if the return code is 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in this.

The call:

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(...)
```

kicks off the process.  The line:

```
output = "".join(pipe.stdout.readlines())
```

reads the process's stdout (if there were error output it could get jammed up, but since you did not redirect stderr this is safe; in the more general case, you need to use the `.communicate()` function to avoid possible wedging).  You might think: well, now that I've read all the output, the subprocess has clearly finished, so `pipe.returncode` should be set.  But in fact, if you replace:

```
sts = pipe.returncode
if sts is None: sts = 0
```

with code that includes a diagnostic of some sort (or just delete the second line entirely), you'll find that, at least on some systems sometimes, `sts` *is* `None`.  The reason is that the `subprocess` module has not had a chance to retrieve it yet.  You should replace those lines with:

```
sts = pipe.wait()
```

to collect the result and obviate the need for the `is None` test.  (It's safe to call `.wait()` even if you've used `.communicate()` and/or already called `.wait()`.)

The `"".join(...)` can be done slightly more efficiently by using just:

```
output = pipe.stdout.read()
```

All that said, it does get the full output for me.  Perhaps you're reading from something that uses just `'\r'` for newlines and your Python was built without universal-newline support?  (If I run something that produces `\r`-for-newline I still get all the lines, separated by actual newlines.)

Comment: thanks for this excellent explanation.  I've learned a lot already.  However, I think you're onto something with the newline thing.  I am only getting `'\n'` back from my function.  Can you please expand on the newline issue?

Comment: Per the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open), "universal newline" means: when reading an input stream, an input line that "ends with" any of plain `\r` or `\r\n` or plain `\n` will make Python "see" just a simple `\n` character.  But this requires that Python be built with the support.  If not, a plain `\r` would be seen as `\r`, and if you `print` the resulting string you might not see everything.  For example: `>>> print 'something\relse'` *appears* to print `elsething`.

Comment: That makes sense, but shouldn't I be getting all the output with `\n` mixed in?  Instead I am simply getting a single `'\n'` even when I know the subprocess (ffmpeg in this case) is outputting a bunch more.

Comment: You should get everything it sends to `stdout`.  Maybe it sends other stuff to `stderr`?  And: yes, it does: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455532/ffmpeg-and-pythons-subprocess

Comment: Thanks torek.  Redirecting stderr didn't work either, however one of  the posts on your link suggests using `pexpect`.  Its approximately one billion times easier to implement and outputs just fine (well, with a few nasty escape chars).  Appreciate your time very much

Comment: Yes, `pexpect` is the way to go for more complex cases, including programs that insist on being "interactive" even when they are not. :-)