# Replacement for getstatusoutput in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python

Since the commands module is deprecated since Python 2.6, I'm looking into the best way to replace [commands.getstatusoutput](http://docs.python.org/library/commands.html?highlight=commands#commands.getstatusoutput) which returns a tuple of the command's return code and output. The [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module is rather obvious, however, it doesn't offer a direct replacement for getstatusoutput. A potential solution is discussed in a related question concerning [getstatusoutput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202078/python-getstatusoutput-replacement-not-returning-full-output) - however, I'm not looking into rewriting the original function (which has less then 10 LOC anyway) but would like to know if there is a more straightforward way.

Comment: Did you read the answer to that question? The Pythonic solution is to use `Popen.communicate`, then read the `Popen.statuscode`. That will give you the stdout and stderr in separate strings, though.

Comment: Yes, but as I said, I'm not looking into rewriting the commands module's function. What the original function does is to simply use os.popen, then read and close the pipe. That's what the suggested new version does as well (once fixed w/ what's written in the answer). However, I was hoping for anything resembling that function in the standard library w/out having to maintain my own replacement.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no direct replacement, because `commands.getstatusoutput` was a bad API; it combines stderr and stdout without giving an option to retrieve them separately.

The convenience API that you should be using is `subprocess.check_output` as it will throw an exception if the command fails.

Otherwise, it does appear somewhat of a deficiency that `subprocess` doesn't provide a method to retrieve output and status in a single call, but it's easy to work around; here's what the answer to the linked question should have been:

```
def get_status_output(*args, **kwargs):
    p = subprocess.Popen(*args, **kwargs)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    return p.returncode, stdout, stderr
```

If you want `stdout` and `stderr` together, use `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it basically told me what I needed to know. Just a hint: "communicate() returns a tuple (stdout, stderr)"

Answer (score 10):

getstatusoutput is back (from python 3.1) :) See: http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html#legacy-shell-invocation-functions

Comment: I wouldn't use it though, its gone again at least in Python 3.6.4

Comment: @radtek `import subprocess;subprocess.getstatusoutput("echo a")` still works for me (Python 3.6.4 | Anaconda).

Comment: The question was about `import commands` as in `commands.getstatusoutput`, that's gone.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question from the title: here's asyncio-based `getstatusoutput()` implementation -- it is [code example from the docs that is modified to follow more closely `subprocess.getstatusoutput()` interface](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#example):

```
import asyncio
import locale
from asyncio.subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT

@asyncio.coroutine
def getstatusoutput(cmd):
    proc = yield from asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(cmd,
            stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    try:
        stdout, _ = yield from proc.communicate()
    except:
        try:
            proc.kill()
        except ProcessLookupError: # process is already dead
            pass
        raise
    finally:
        exitcode = yield from proc.wait()
    # return text
    output = stdout.decode(locale.getpreferredencoding(False))
    # universal newlines mode
    output = output.replace("\r\n", "\n").replace("\r", "\n")
    if output[-1:] == "\n": # remove a trailing newline
        output = output[:-1]
    return (exitcode, output)
```

It works both Windows and Unix. To run it ([from the same example](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#example)):

```
import os
from contextlib import closing

if os.name == 'nt': # Windows
    loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
else:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
with closing(loop):
    coro = getstatusoutput('python -m platform')
    exitcode, stdout = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
    if exitcode == 0:
        print("Platform:", stdout)
    else:
        print("Python failed with exit code %s: %s" % (exitcode, stdout))
```