# Cast output of Tensorflow Object Detection at Desktop wallpaper Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, opencv, ubuntu

I am trying to setup My Ubuntu Desktop wallpaper that accepts a Live video feed from webcam using opencv and after performing some object detection I accept it as Opencv feed where I am able to Display it using `cv2.imshow`.

But instead of Using Imshow is it possible to cast the output of object detection as ubuntu desktop live Wallpaper.

I am even able to setup live video from youtube as Ubuntu live wallpaper using `cvlc` but unable to understand how to do that from opencv output.

Comment: how much trouble are you willing to go to? if `cvlc` works, there's a way but it could be complicated and I haven't done that yet

Comment: basically, run `cvlc` to receive a stream, and use cv::VideoWriter to send a stream there. might require OpenCV with gstreamer or ffmpeg

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I am doing it to create an open source alternative to Hola lens and I am on the last stage of deployment as a result there is no chance of stepping back let me try it with CV::VideoWriter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to go with a lot of trouble as looks like its never been implemented but you can try implementing by one of the following ways :

1. Try saving the frames and consciously deleting the old frame at a
   same time changing background from os call.
2. if you are able to make `cvlc` run You can try running it by cv::VideoWriter or [Streaming
   video to localhost](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/09/02/opencv-stream-video-to-web-browser-html-page/) and then using similar YouTube approach you
   were doing.
3. You can Try using Streamlink/MPV/Xwinwrap fork.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the desired results using `cv2.imwrite()` and then try the methods described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85162/how-can-i-change-the-wallpaper-using-a-python-script) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344557/replacement-for-getstatusoutput-in-python-3)

Comment: it will result in a lot of frames getting added and its really slow