# pexpect.run() terminates before ending ffmpeg without finishing the conversion

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pexpect

I'm working on a python script that does a custom conversion of videos via ffmpeg.

My problem is that the execution of ffmpeg stops suddenly after a bit of conversion (usually 3-4 mb out of 100mb) with a None exit code.

I'm using the **pexpect** library. Currently I do not check the progress but I will in a close future. It seems that I am right using pexpect regarding these questions [FFMPEG and Pythons subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1455532/1729524) and [Getting realtime output from ffmpeg to be used in progress bar (PyQt4, stdout)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7632589/1729524). This is the command that I'm running (I have checked that it's exactly this one)

```
nice ffmpeg -i '/full/path' -s 640x360 -strict experimental -vcodec libx264
   -f mp4 -  coder 0 -bf 0 -refs 1 -flags2 -wpred-dct8x8 -level 30 -crf 26
   -bufsize 4000k -maxrate 350k -preset medium -acodec libvo_aacenc
   -ar 48000.0 -ab 128K -threads 2 -y '/full/path/out'
```

I am using *nice* but I have tried also without it and the result ends up being the same.

I'm running pexpect this way:

```
output, exit = pexpect.run(self.command(), withexitstatus=True,\
                                   logfile=logfile)
print output
print exit
```

Of course I have tried the same command on the command line and it works fine.

Any clue on what might be happening?

Comment: Why pexpect? What happens if you use Popen from subprocess?

Comment: @albert I will try it know. I don't really like the solution because in "the next iteration" I should be using pexpect to check the advance of the operation. But I'll try and post the results in a bit

Comment: I will work until the end of the conversion but it seems to be working. But still I don't really like the solution and I will probably be facing the same problem in a few weeks...

Comment: Doing that via Popen should also be easy. I'm not sure if pexpect gives you any useful advantage here. But in any case: It seems like pexpect is buggy here for you. You should try to debug pexpect.

Comment: I have found the bug (I should have looked more carefully). http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3316509&group_id=59762&atid=492077 After this I trust the library a bit less so I'll go with your solution @albert. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being a bug in pexpect run function regarding the timeout. I have found the bug that was reported before me (yes, I forget to check ;))

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3316509&group_id=59762&atid=492077

Sadly the bug is really old and it explains how to solve the little bug. As a workaround I could just rewrite my code using spawn instead.

I don't really like the idea of using a code with trivial bugs that is still unmaintained so I have writen the code using Popen as Albert suggested.

I will wait some time to make the choice of going taking the chances with pexpect (if the code seems reliable).

For the record, here is my working code:

```
    output = file(LOG_FILE, 'a')
    args = shlex.split(self.command_video())
    return subprocess.call(args, stdout=output, stderr=output)
```

Thanks for the help.